# How to increase security of a Laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, seo

I am a beginner in Laravel. I have a live project(ex:https://seniorcitizenhospital.com/) made with Laravel.

while I use `site::https://seniorcitizenhospital.com/` in google search engine it gives me a search result with some Chinese language(red color) like below image

[image]

But there is no use any other language this site. So is this one kind of malware or hacking issue? If something like that how could I protect my site from these issues?

Anybody Help Please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to have removed? Please add some details - how is this related to security?

Comment: @FrankProvost...Sorry for the previous question. I have updated my post. Please have a look

Comment: @ArafatRahman Have you tried the google url inspection tool to find out what page is showing these characters?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this can happen in your case - for me the site / link of google leads to your 404 page which does not provide any meta description. However, it provides a title which is clearly not shown on the page. You should force a re-index of your page in the google webmaster tools. Also you shoul check if you have any laravel / composer packages installed that might manipulate output when 404 page is raised as the japanese text seems to be advertisement it "smells" a bit like scam.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to set a dedicated 404 page that returns if no page found.

Currently, whatever URL I place on your website, it returns me 200 all the time.

[image]

One of the reasons can be because it already returns 200 no matter what circumstances.

**Update:**
Even if I look into the security check of your website, the report shows me some malware on your site. Check details here-

- https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/seniorcitizenhospital.com
- https://sg.godaddy.com/web-security/website-security-check/results?site=https%3A%2F%2Fseniorcitizenhospital.com%2F

You need to ensure that your website doesn't contain any kinds of malware before asking google to re-index.